# sqlite3 insert using python and python cgi

Tags: python, sqlite, fastcgi

1. In *db.py*,I can use a function(*func insert*) insert data into sqlite correctly.
2. Now I want to insert data into sqlite through python-fastcgi, in
       fastcgi (just named *post.py* ) I can get the request data correctly,but
       when I call *db.insert*,it gives me internal server error.

I already did `chmod 777 slqite.db`. Anyone know whats problem?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post some code.

Comment: turn on the debug flag of fastcgi, and find where is the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ffinally I found the answer:

the sqlite3 library needs write permissions also on the directory that contains it, probably because it needs to create a lockfile.

Therefor when I use sql to insert data there is no problem, but when I do it through web cgi,fastcgi etc）to insert data there would be an error.

Just add write permission to the directory.